# Явное инстанцирование шаблонного конструктора и функция-члена

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Чтобы использовать шаблонный класс, определенный в `.cpp` файле, можно явно инстанцировать этот класс:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
   template<typename G>
   A(G) {}

   template<typename G>
   void foo(G) {}
}

template
class A<int>;
```

Надо ли также инстанцировать его шаблонный конструктор и шаблонную функцию-член?

Странно, но если использовать конструктор, не инстанцируя его явно, у меня всё работает без ошибок, а вот уже без явного инстанцирования функции её использование выдаёт ошибку линковки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явное инстанцирование шаблонного класса автоматически явно инстанцирует все его члены, кроме унаследованных членов и членов, которые являются вложенными шаблонами. Что неудивительно: о каком явном инстанцировании может идти речь, если значения шаблонных параметров вложенных шаблонов неизвестны?

Если вам действительно нужно, чтобы на данные методы был наложен еще один вложенный уровень шаблонности, то явно инстанцировать их вам придется явно и независимо.

> Странно, но если использовать конструктор, не инстанцируя его явно, у меня всё работает без ошибок,

Скорее всего потому, что ваш шаблонный конструктор просто не используется вообще. В некоторых контекстах шаблонные конструкторы не рассматриваются в качестве кандидатов. Например, шаблонный конструктор не будет рассматриваться в качестве конструктора копирования.

---

Не совсем понятна структура вашего примера. Определения методов у вас располагаются прямо в определении класса. Если это определение видно из всех единиц трансляции, то зачем вам понадобилось явное инстанцирование? Если это определение не видно из других единиц трансляции, то как вы тогда работаете с этим классом из других единиц трансляции?

Comment: А как так происходит, что я явно не инстанцирую конструктор, но могу использовать его без ошибок в gcc? Это баг?

Comment: @Sergei: Примеры приводите. Скорее всего вам просто показалось, что вы использовали этот конструктор.

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую сделать минимальный пример

Comment: Всё, был не прав. Действительно, с конструктором тоже ошибка

Comment: Ответ на вопрос: не видно, использую определение класса в `.h` без реализаций методов в других файлах, только в 1 `.cpp` файле есть определение с реализациями

Comment: @Sergei: OK, но тогда в `.cpp` файле определения шаблонных методов класса не могут быть указаны прямо в определении класса (inline). Ибо в таком случае у вас получается два разных определения одного и того же шаблона класса и эти определения существенно отличаются: настолько, что это является нарушением ODR.

Comment: Я не включая этот `.h` в `.cpp` с реализациями, ошибок не выдаёт

Comment: @Sergei: Я понимаю, что вы не включали (тогда ошибка была бы сразу). Ошибка, о которой я говорю, относится к классу NDR (no diagnostic required). У компилятора нет возможности проверить одинаковость объявлений в разных единицах трансляции, поэтому неудивительно, что "ошибок не выдает". Обеспечивать такую одинаковость - это полностью ваша обязанность.

Comment: И что делать в таком случае? Получается в `.cpp` без нарушения ODR не написать

Comment: @Sergei: Почему не написать? Просто уберите из определения класса определения методов. Такое определение класса можно спокойно поместить в заголовочный файл - одно на всех. А уж определения методов и явные инстанцирования пусть сидят в `.cpp` файле. Так обычно делают. Вам это по какой-то причине не подходит?

Comment: Подходит, но так разве можно? Как другие `.cpp` файлы узнают о методах класса, если их нет в `.h` файле?

Comment: @Sergei: Методы, разумеется,  должны быть в `.h` файле, но только в виде *объявлений*, а не *определений*. То есть тела методов в `.h` файле должны отсутствовать. Определения (тела) методов идут в `.cpp` файл.